# Ajax update not rendering fieldsets in target container

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, fieldset

I have a datatable and an ajax listener to update a detail section for the selected row in the table:

```
    <pf40:dataTable id="memberNameList1"
      value="#{pc_NameView.lazyModel}" var="varNameList"
      styleClass="cleantable" border="1" cellpadding="2"
      emptyMessage="#{resourceBundleLabels.noRecordsFound}"
      cellspacing="0" width="100%" paginator="true"
      rows="#{pc_NameView.maxNoOfRows}"
      paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink}  {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
      paginatorPosition="bottom"
      selection="#{pc_NameView.selectedNameSummary}"
      rowKey="#{varNameList.Id}"
      widgetVar="nameWvar"
      rowIndexVar="findex"                           
      rowStyleClass="#{(empty pc_NameView.selectedNameSummary) ? '' : pc_NameView.selectedNameSummary.Id eq varmemberNameList.Id ? 'ui-state-highlight' : ''}"
      rowsPerPageTemplate="#{pc_NameView.maxResultsPerPageOptions}"
                lazy="true">
<pf40:ajax event="page" update=":detailSection" process=":detailSection"></pf40:ajax>
```

The detailSection contains fieldset components which in turn contain composite components.

```
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="detailSection">
<h:form id="detailForm"   rendered="some_condition">

   <!-- Member Name Detail section -->
   <h:panelGroup layout="block" class="sixteen col">
      <h:panelGroup styleClass="divtablesummaryrecordsperpage" layout="block">
         <mycomposite:mycomp imageSrc="images/icons/icon_help.png" />
      </h:panelGroup>

      <pf40:fieldset id="detailSection1"   legend="#{resourceBundleLabels.nameDetailsLabel}"   toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500">
                         some_content_including_composites
                </pf40:fieldset>
                <pf40:fieldset id="detailSection2"   legend="#{resourceBundleLabels.nameDetails2Label}"   toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500">
                         some_content_including_composites
                </pf40:fieldset>
                <pf40:fieldset id="detailSection3"   legend="#{resourceBundleLabels.nameDetails3Label}"   toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500">
                         some_content_including_composites
                </pf40:fieldset>
</h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Only the first fieldset renders. The others do not. I have a detail link on every line in the table and the same behavior was observed when any link is clicked to view details. However I was able to change the ajax tag to the standard JSF ajax tag and all the field sets were rendered correctly. Unfortunately i can't use the standard JSF ajax tag to listen for primefaces datatable events.

```
    <h:commandLink action="#{pc_NameView.showRowDetails}" onclick="nameWvar.unselectAllRows(); nameWvar.selectRow(#{findex})">
   <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{varNameList}" target="#{pc_NameView.selectedNameSummary}" />
   <f:ajax execute=":detailSection" render=":detailSection" />View Details
</h:commandLink>
```